# Proving $\lVert T\rVert <\infty $ for $Tf(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}f\big(\frac{x}{2}\big)$ (with $L^2$ norm on $f$)

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Given $$T:PC[0,1]\to PC[0,1]$$ $$Tf(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}f\big(\frac{x}{2}\big)$$ I'm trying to prove that: $\lVert T\rVert <\infty $

where:

$$ \lVert T \rVert = \sup\{\lVert Tf(x) \rVert \mid \lVert f(x)\rVert_{L^2}=1\}$$

$$\lVert f(x)\rVert_{L^2}^2= \int_0^1|f(x)|^2dx$$

I feel that this is supposed to be relatively simple, but perhaps I'm too rusty on some details to be able to accomplish this. What's confusing me is the fraction inside of $f$ (if it were only $x$, I would be able to get to $...\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\lVert f\rVert_{L^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ and would be done).

I have tried 'getting rid' of the $\frac{x}{2}$ by change of variables, but that seems to mess things up due to the absolute value (which is required since $f$'s range is complex). I also considered using the sup norm on $f$, as it is in $PC[0,1]$, but that didn't help me get to bounding the supremum.

What am I missing?

Comment: What fraction does is that it squeezes the integrand $f$ to the interval $[0,1/2]$. Think like this; If $f$ is constant and $||f||=c$ then $||T(f)||$ should be $c/(2\sqrt{2})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of using change of variable is fine. Letting $t = \frac{x}{2}$, we have $dx = 2dt$, and if $x$ ranges from $0$ to $1$, $t$ ranges from
$0$ to $1/2$, so:

$$\int_0^1 \left| f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \right| dx = 2 \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} |f(t)| dt $$

You can think of this as defining a real function $g$ as $g(x) =  \left| f\left(x\right) \right|$, then the equality above becomes:

$$\int_0^1 g\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \ dx = 2 \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} g(t)\  dt $$

Can you fill in the rest from here?